# Unity - custom Export and Import FBX Data

Tags: unity, c#, 3dsmax, fbx

I am trying to write custom data inside a FBX file from 3dsmax at export time. This might be possible even if I don't know right now how to do that.
But my question would be how can I read those custom FBX data inside Unity on import.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great answer from [**theodox**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936075/theodox) on [**Stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347772/unity-custom-export-and-import-fbx-data).

> The easy way to do this is to add a custom attribute to an object in
>   the Maya/Max scene and then use the [Unity
>   AssetPostprocessor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html)
>   to find the attribute and parse it's data.
>
> AssetPostprocessor has an
>   [OnPostprocessGameObjectWithUserProperties](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPostprocessGameObjectWithUserProperties.html)
>   callback which will be fired for every transform in your fbx file
>   which has a custom attribute applied. You'll want to find your
>   attribute in the postprocessor and do something:

```
public void OnPostprocessGameObjectWithUserProperties(GameObject incomingGameObject, string[] incomingPropetyNames, object[] incomingValues)
{
    var thisModelImporter = this.assetImporter as ModelImporter;
    var meta_key = "your_attribute_name";
    if (incomingPropetyNames.Contains(meta_key))
    {
        string raw_data = (string)incomingValues[Array.IndexOf(incomingPropetyNames, meta_key)];
        // use the data here....
    }
}
```

> It's annoying that there's no standard way to create file-level
>   metadata, I usually just attach my 'top level' data to something like
>   the root of the model in the FBX file. You can pass complex data by
>   storing things as a JSON blob and passing the JSON as a string
>   attribute; that's usually easier to maintain than a web of multiple
>   attribute names and types.
>
> Be warned that FBX tends to mangle long attibute names - I'm not sure
>   where the cutoff is but extremely long attribute names sometime get
>   truncated to a meaningless string like `FBXASC_012345" if they exceed
>   the magic character count.
>
> The only thing you cant do easily this way is vertex or face level
>   data; while you could pack that sort of thing into custom attributes,
>   there's not a rock-solid guarantee that the indices you see in
>   Max/Maya will be the same as the ones in the FBX.  For that type of
>   data vertex colors or extra UV channels are good places to store extra
>   information, though it's up to you to come up with a way of deciding
>   what a given color or UV means.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write an asset post processor to tell Unity what you want to do with that data.

Here is a link to the documentation :-

[AssetPostprocessor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html)

A script on how this can be implemented :)

https://gist.github.com/darktable/2425709